# ./configure can't find evp.h

Tags: php, linux, debian

I've installed the following packages on my Debian 6.0, after setting my versions in the sources.list to 7.0:

- libssl-dev
- openssl
- openssl-common

I've verified that `/usr/include/openssl/evp.h` exists with a permission of 777, and then I've ran ./configure like this:

`./configure --with-zlib-dir --with-freetype-dir --enable-mbstring --with-libxml-dir=/usr --enable-soap --enable-calendar --with-mcrypt --disable-rpath --enable-inline-optimization --with-zlib --enable-sockets --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-pcntl --enable-mbregex --enable-exif --enable-bcmath --with-mhash --enable-zip --with-pcre-regex --with-mysql --with-pdo-mysql --with-mysqli --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data --enable-ftp --with-kerberos --with-gettext --with-xmlrpc --enable-opcache --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2 --with-config-file-path=/etc/php5/apache2 --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php5/conf.d --with-openssl-dir=/usr/include/openssl`

However, I still get an error from configure that evp.h could not be found.

Comment: No, I resorted to using yum in `CentOS` and the `remi-php55` repository. You can use the `ondrej` repository for `Debian` and rid yourself of the trouble.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/a/544149/155703

Comment: I also have this exact error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @RandomSeed all test cases fail with the links advice

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was struggling with this problem for a long time, and this ended up working for me:

Instead of `--with-openssl-dir=/usr/include/openssl` just use `--with-openssl`

Comment: In my case (7.1.0RC3), --with-openssl is not a configuration. However, --with-openssl-dir did fix my problem. Thank you so much :D

Comment: if you check the command  `./configure --help` you will see this line : `--with-openssl-dir=DIR  SNMP: openssl install prefix`.  It's concerning SNMP only.

Comment: Thank you for adding this answer. It helped me and this is still relevant. I was building PHP 7.3.5 on Debian 9 (May-2019)!

Comment: worked for me installing PHP 7.1.3 from source on ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 11):

If `./configure ...` can not find `/usr/include/openssl/evp.h` it is most likely you have not installed openssl, namely the header. So if you are using CentOs you should first do:

```
yum install openssl-devel
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a bug in [php bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72363&thanks=10)

The cause of this is because after running the command 'phpize' the configure script has a variable (PHP_OPENSSL_DIR) that is not set "yes"

So you should do:

```
export PHP_OPENSSL_DIR=yes
./configure -with-openssl-dir=/usr/include/openssl
```